# How to reduce network upload in ejb3 remote client?

Tags: ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss6.x, networkstream

I wrote an ejb3 client that communicates with a remote server using jndi, but, every time I call a remote method, there is a data upload of about 2KB, even if I 'm doing  an atomic operation.

I tried to reduce the dimension of the remote Class, without any success.

Where i can look to optimize my upload performances? (The application server is Jboss AS6)

Comment: I thought EJB 3 took care of all those early issues with "chattiness".  Can somebody tell me why the EJB model isn't a failure?

Comment: @duffymo Your question doesn't seem to clarify the poster's question.

Comment: And your crystal clear answer is....?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded jboss to 7.1.1 and the amount of data uploaded by the client **collapsed by 20 times**.